# Can an optimization constraint be implemented with 2 variable that declared with different feature?

Tags: python, optimization, error-handling, docplex, operations-research

My goal is to write the following constraint with the doxplex.mp.model with Python API:
P[t,j] >= s[t-j+1] - sum(s[k=t-j+2] from k to t) for t = 1,....,N, j = 1,...,t

**my code.**

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
clsp = Model(name = 'capacitated lot sizing problem')
no_of_period = 8
period_list = [t for t in range(1, no_of_period+1)]
s_indicator = clsp.binary_var_dict(period_list, name = 's_indicator')
p_indicator = clsp.binary_var_matrix(period_list, period_list, name = 'p_indicator')
m_8 = clsp.add_constraints(p_indicator[t,j] >= s_indicator[t-j+1] - clsp.sum(s_indicator[t-j+2]  for j in range(1,t+1))  
                           for j in t for t in period_list )
```

**Output: Keyerror 0**
**Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Just to clarify, the sum is from t-j+2 to t. What happens when j >= t+2?

Comment: So you mean i should use the If.. condition?

Comment: I'm only asking what it is you want. As with all programming, if you use an index that is outside of the range of acceptable you will get a key error.

Comment: Ohh what I want is Example: p[1,1] >= s1 - s2 as t = 1, j = 1,,t which is j also = 1 and so on. But i got an error and struggle to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code extract is not correct Python (for j in t). I had to modify it to make it run:

```
m_8 = clsp.add_constraints\
    (p_indicator[t,j] >= s_indicator[t-j+1] - clsp.sum(s_indicator[t-j+2]  for j in range(1,t+1))
                           for j in period_list for t in period_list )
```

Which gives ma a `KeyError: 9` exception.

To fix this, remember that `binary_var_matrix` creates a Python dictionary, whose keys are the first argument, here period_list, ranging from 1 to 8.

To investigate this I wrote this small code to investigate all possible keys generated by your code:

```
ke = 0
for t in period_list:
    for j in period_list:
        ix = t-j+2
        if ix not in period_list:
            ke += 1
            print(f"** Key error[{ke}], t={t},j={j}, t-j+2={t-j+2}")
```

Prints 22 key errors, for example `t=8, j=1` computes `(t-j+2)=9` which is outside the dictionary key set.

To summarize: check your indices w.r.t the keys of the variable dictionaries in your model.

Comment: The code above is really helpful but I wonder if I could the use the following code, too?for t in period_list: 
    for j in range(1,t+1):  
        s_indicator[9] = 0
        m_09 = clsp.add_constraint(p_indicator[t,j] >= s_indicator[t-j+1] - clsp.sum(s_indicator[t-j+2] for j in range(1,t+1)))

Comment: I cannot read your code snippet with two `=` on same line. I suggest you build your constraint with custom code for each value of `j`: build lhs, build set of indices for the sum, then build the rhs and add each constraint `lhs==rhs`  one at a time.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! That was really helpful.